# How to use Keycloak JavaScript adapter for Authorization Code with PKCE flow in a React app?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, oauth-2.0, keycloak, openid-connect

I have a React app which will be the public client for a Keycloak authorization server.
I want to authenticate a user using the **Javascript adapter provided by Keycloak** and as Grant Type, I want to use **Authorization Code with PKCE flow**.